# How do you hang a casement window sash?

Tags: windows

I have Anderson casement windows I want to rehang because some sashes are rubbing up against the bottom or side.  I think the rubbing is just from the sash sagging over time, they were installed in 1970. I'm having a hard time keeping the sash centered while I screw the hinges in.

Any tips or methods for hanging a sash?  Should I replace any parts while I'm at it?

Comment: How about a pic? Are you replacing the hinges? How about the casement operators? Are you going to strip all the old layers of paint and refinish?

Comment: I was going to keep the hardware but I could replace it.  The sashes are old so I've had to buy replacement parts from retailers other than Anderson.  I once removed a sash and tried to rehang it but I had a problem keeping it square within the opening.  Should i shim around the sash while screwing in the hinges?  Do I attach the sash when the window is in the closed position?